# Problema com lista simples circular em C

Tags: c

**Estou tentando realizar uma lista circular porém sempre que compilo esta dando erro. Poderia me apontar o erro?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct lista
{
    int info;
    struct lista *prox;
} lista;

lista* criarLista(void)
{
    return NULL;
}

lista* inserirListaFim(lista* l, int i)
{
    lista *novo = (lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));
    novo->info = i;
    novo->prox = l;
    return novo;
}

int listaVazia(lista *l)
{
    if(l==NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void imprimeLista(lista *l)
{
    lista *p = l;
    if(listaVazia(l))
    {
        printf("Lista Vazia!!!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            printf(" | %d |", p->info);
            p = p->prox;
        }
        while(p != l);
    }
}


int main()
{
    lista* l = (lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));
    l = criarLista();
    l = inserirListaFim(l, 1);
    l = inserirListaFim(l, 4);
    l = inserirListaFim(l, 7);
    imprimeLista(l);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Qual a mensagem de erro informada pelo compilador?

Comment: Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Comment: Fiz a depuração e é no instrução `imprimeLista(l);` que o sistema está parando.

Comment: sim, o problema é que não to conseguindo arrumar esta parte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O primeiro erro é esse malloc no inicio que aloca a memoria para a variável `l` e logo em seguida você atribui `NULL` para `l` com a função `criarLista`, vazando a memoria.

Atribua diretamente a função criarLista para l:

`lista* l = criarLista();`

O segundo erro é a instrução `printf(" | %d |", p->info);` de `imprimeLista` que desreferencia `p` sem verificar se ele está nulo ou não.

Verique no while se p contém um valor:

`while(p && p != l);`

Comment: Certo, qual a melhor forma de resolver este problema?

Comment: @GuilhermeBarbosa atualizei a resposta com as soluções.

Comment: deu certo aqui, muito obrigado!